# Rest api - update single field of resource

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

Lets say I have rest endpoint for my Driver resource.
I have PUT method like this

```
myapi/drivers/{id}

{body of put method}
```

I need to add functionality which will allow to 'enable' and 'disable' driver

Is it good idea to create new endpoint for that  like this?

```
PUT myapi/drivers/{id}/enable/false
```

or it is better to use existing endpoint ? One problem with using existing endpoint is that driver has lot's of fields(almost 30) and sending all those fields just for updating only 'enabled' or 'disable' driver is something overkill.

What do you think?

Comment: `myapi/drivers/{id}?enable=false` how about URL parameter

Comment: you can create to new endpoints `myapi/drivers/{id}/enable/` and `myapi/drivers/{id}/disable/` , this is sometime easier for who is consuming your API.

Comment: this is opinion based, but yeah I'd probably do something similar to what @Nirekin suggested.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is exactly what the HTTP method `PATCH` is made for. It is used in cases where the resource has many fields but you only want to update a few.

Just like with `PUT`, you send a request to `myapi/drivers/{id}`. However, unlike with `PUT`, you only send the fields you want to change in the request body.

Creating endpoints like `myapi/drivers/{id}/enable` is not very RESTful, as "enable" can't really be called a resource on its own.

For an example implementation of a Spring `PATCH` endpoint, please see this [link](http://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring).

Comment: agreed! lots of people think `GET` and `POST` only... plus one

Comment: @Synch what do you think about `myapi/drivers/{id}/is_enabled` and PATCH is_enabled? I would like to communicate to my API users that PATCH is only designed to "toggle" some status in the context of drivers resource. If they want to update any other fields just PUT to `myapi/drivers/{id}`. Does it make sense?

Comment: There are two things you can do. You can create a PATCH endpoint and limit it to only `status`. If the client tries to update anything else, you throw a `406`. In the documentation, you'd need to explain the endpoint is only suitable for one attribute. The other approach is to create a "sub-resource" `myapi/drivers/{id}/status`. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37544666/5771446) for a much more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use PATCH Http metod to update one field

```
PATCH myapi/drivers/{id}/enable
```

Comment: Not good design. RFC mentions patch should contain a request body.