# Using Java Optional in Kotlin DTOs

Tags: java, kotlin, option-type

Currently I'm using Java 8's `Optional` in my Kotlin DTOs as follows:

```
class dto {
    var prop1: String? = null

    var prop2: Optional<String>? = null
}
```

The purpose of it is that for some properties like `prop2` I want to also allow delete in the request. So the value of `prop2` in the DTO is understood as follows:

null => do nothing 
non-empty optional => update value 
empty optional => delete value (set value to null)

Then at some point in the code I'm doing the following:

```
dto.prop2?.let {
    // since it is not null, then we either need to update or delete value
    if (it.isPresent) {
        // indicates update value
        entity.prop2 = it.get()
        // then entity will be saved in DB and column will be updated
    } else {
        // indicates delete/erase value
        entity.prop2 = null
        // then entity will be saved in DB and column value will be set to null
    }
}
```

So my question now is there a *Kotlinish* of achieving the same behavior without having to use Java `Optional`? As I think it is complicated in this way and this also implies having to do `isPresent` check over many parts in the code.

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to do? Are you building a REST api? Are you considering the lost update problem when updating /deleting?

Comment: It is a REST api that receives a DTO and need to update/delete values according to values provided in the DTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to modify only some fields of a resource I would use the HTTP `PATCH` method. You can send a map in the body of your request only with the fields that you want to modify.

If you want to set `prop2` to null, send `{"prop2":null}`. If you want to modify it to a new value, send `{"prop2":"new value"}`. If you want to do nothing, just don't send prop2 in the map.

But if you prefer a more type safe version, you can create a DTO like that:

```
data class UpdateProp2DTO(
    val id: String
    val prop2: String?
)
```

You're going to use use this DTO only if you want to change `prop2`, otherwise just don't use it.

For the `PATCH` method it only makes sense to create a DTO with fewer properties than the resource. If you want to be able to update all properties at once you have the `PUT` method for that and then you just need to replace the whole resource with the DTO provided in the request body.

You can find more information in the accepted answer of this question: [Rest api - update single field of resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921841/rest-api-update-single-field-of-resource). It points to a link describing how to do that with Spring.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could create a sealed class hierarchy of update actions to model this. That should make your code quite readable. Something like this:

```
sealed class UpdateableProperty<out T>
data class Update<T>(val value: T) : UpdateableProperty<T>()
object DoNothing : UpdateableProperty<Nothing>()
object Delete : UpdateableProperty<Nothing>()

data class Dto (
   val prop1: UpdateableProperty<String>,
   val prop2: UpdateableProperty<Int?>
)
```

Now, you can match on the property to decide what to do:

```
when(val prop = dto.prop1) {
    is Update -> repo.update(prop.value)
    is Delete -> repo.delete()
    is DoNothing -> { /* Do nothing */ }
}
```

Comment: This is as idiomatic to Kotlin as it gets wanted to write similar answer, just `object DoNothing : UpdateableProperty<T>()` wouldn't compile, you probably meant `object DoNothing : UpdateableProperty<Any>()`

Comment: @FilipRistic Right, fixed :) I did it by making `T` covariant and using `Nothing` though.