# How to choose an approach for updating resources in REST

Tags: rest, http, post, asp.net-web-api, put

I am considering two approaches when updating rest api and i am not sure how to choose which approach to follow

For example

```
GET /service/1000

{
"service_id": 1000,
"name": "Some service"
"status": "ACTIVE"
}
```

Now If I want to update this service I could do

```
PUT /service/1000
{
"service_id": 1000,
"name": "Some service"
"status": "INACTIVE"
}
```

or

```
POST /service/1000/update-status
{
"status": "INACTIVE"
}
```

or even

```
POST /service/1000/activate
{

}
```

and

```
POST /service/1000/deactivate
{

}
```

So my question is what is the rule of thumb to follow when choosing approach how to update REST?

EDIT
This question is not about when to use POST/PATCH/PUT, it is about should resource be update calling the same resource, or should it be updated using an action. For example, twitter uses actions https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST API - PUT vs PATCH with real life examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459418/rest-api-put-vs-patch-with-real-life-examples)

Comment: The idea behind REST is to have URIs that match resources, not actions, so the `/update-status`, `/activate` and `/deactivate` should not be used.

Comment: Twitter for example uses actions https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index

Answer (score 0):

From what you are considering `put` is more appropriate however I in some cases `patch` is more appropriate so when you are changing the value of resources you consider using `patch` but when you are adding a new property `put` is more appropriate see---
[REST API PATCH or PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241893/rest-api-patch-or-put)

Comment: That wasnt really the question