# Change only 1 Parameter with PutRequest?

Tags: java, microservices

I have a question. Is it possible to be able to change only one parameter in a PutRequest?
I didn't find anything on the internet about this.

```
    @GetMapping("/templates/{user_name}/{template_id}")
    public Template retrieveTemplate(@PathVariable("user_name") String user_name,@PathVariable("template_id") int template_id)
    {
        return templateRepository.findByTemplateIdAndUserName(template_id, user_name);

    }
```

This is my GetRequest and I want that only the parameter template can be changed.

Comment: Could you improve your question? I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry. It's got a database called Templates. And in this database there are the parameters id, user_name, template_id and a string template. When I start a PutRequest I shouldn't be allowed to change id template_id and user_name. Only template should be able to be changed.

Comment: What you require is called a PATCH in HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom has already mentioned, in case you'd like only partially update your existing entity then you must be using **PATCH** HTTP verb. More information you can find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24241955/5178057).

Also here is [a small guide](https://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring) telling the difference between these two methods.

Finally, the code snippet that could help you will be looking:

```
@PatchMapping("/templates/{user_name}/{template_id}")
public Template updateTemplate(@PathVariable("user_name") String user_name, 
                               @PathVariable("template_id") int template_id, 
                               @RequestBody Template template)  {
    return templateService.updateTemplate(template_id, template);
}

@Service
public static class TemplateService {

    @Autowired
    private TemplateRepository templateRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Template updateTemplate(int id, Template updateTemplate) {
        Template foundTemplate = templateRepository.findById(id);
        foundTemplate.setTemplate(updateTemplate.getTemplate());
        return foundTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Doncarlito87, I'm glad that it was helpful to you! Can you mark my answer an a correct one, please?

Comment: I would like to but i dont have more than 15 reputations. So Stack Over Flow dont allow me to do it. Sry.

Comment: ah, no problem then :) Happy coding!