# With REST, should I use PUT or PATCH to edit a secondary ressource?

Tags: rest

So I have users and each user has a car. A user:

```
{
  name: 'Bob',
  car: {
    brand: 'Ford'
  }
}
```

To update Bob's car I could use an endpoint `PUT /users/1` and update the entirety of Bob, or use an endpoint `PATCH /users/1` and specify in the body that I only want to update Bob's car.

But if I want a route that only refers to Bob's car `/users/1/car` what method should I use to update the car? PUT, PATCH, or something else?

car is called a secondary resource of the user I believe, but in this case, I do not know what is the entity, is it the user or is it the car? If it's the car, then I believe I should use PUT, but if it is still the user then it should be PATCH.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241893/should-i-use-patch-or-put-in-my-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

> With REST, should I use PUT or PATCH to edit a secondary resource?

Careful - [secondary resource](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.5) can be understood to mean something very different from what you are describing here.

---

An important constraint in the REST architectural style is the [uniform interface constraint](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5).  Among other things, this means that request semantics are the same for all target resources.

Therefore: PUT and PATCH messages that target `/users/1/car` should have the same semantics as PUT and PATCH messages that target `/users/1` should have the same semantics as PUT and PATCH message that target `/questions/76036040/with-rest-should-i-use-put-or-patch-to-edit-a-secondary-ressource`.

Specifically: we use PUT when the request body is a representation of our desired state for the target resource.  We use PATCH when the request body is a patch-document, which is to say a description of a set of changes that should be made to the target resource.

---

> in this case, I do not know what is the entity, is it the user or is it the car? If it's the car, then I believe I should use PUT, but if it is still the user then it should be PATCH.

Doesn't matter - PUT and PATCH are about representations of *resources*, not representations of *entities*.  Our REST API hides our domain entities behind a facade that looks like a web site; the semantics of the messages we are sending are expressed in the abstractions of the web site, not the underlying implementation.

---

> So if my route is /users/1/car and changes the entirety of user 1 car, then it is PUT?

If the target URI is /users/1/car, and the payload is a complete replacement representation of the /users/1/car resource, then the method should be PUT.

If the target URI is /users/1/car, and the payload is a patch-document that describes a set of changes to the representation of the /users/1/car resource, then the method should be PATCH.

The fact that there is also a /users/1 resource which may be impacted by the changes in /users/1/car is not relevant to the question.

Note that sending a PATCH to /users/1/car with a patch document that describes a set of changes to /users/1 is completely nonsensical (it is misleading to general purpose HTTP components who don't know that the two resources are related to each other).

Comment: So if my route is /users/1/car and changes the entirety of user 1 car, then it is PUT? Because I had someone make the argument that it only changes a part of user 1 so it should be PATCH, but the route target user 1 car, not user 1.